# Mysql between two datetime columns

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, between

I have the following code and it doesn't seem to be generating the expected results:

```
$date_from = '2012-04-27 18:19:33';
$date_to = '2012-05-29 00:59:57';

$database->connect(); 
        $ancestors = mysql_query('
            SELECT * FROM ' . $database->db_prefix . 'comments e
                WHERE e.created BETWEEN "' . $date_from . '" AND "' . $date_to . '" AND   
                    e.ancestors = "' . $comment["id"] . '" AND e.user_id != "' . $user->user_object["id"] . '" AND
                        NOT EXISTS
                        (
                            SELECT null 
                            FROM ' . $database->db_prefix . 'notifications d
                            WHERE  d.target_id = e.id
                        )
                        ORDER BY e.created DESC
        ', $database->connection_handle);
    $database->close();
```

It may be a silly error.. But I'm finding it hard to be sure when i'm unsure if the select statement BETWEEN and the dates being used are valid MYSQL things.

Any help would be great. I have been scouring and what I am doing seems to be correct thus the confusion.

EDITED //

I have many comments made between the date_from and date_to dates and there are no notifications in the notifications table (not exists  part)... So basically, I should get about 25 comments back... Instead I just get one comment returned which has a date of 2012-05-29 00:23:39

EDITED //

Is it because you can only compare a date to a date.. and a time to a time? How might I adapt the mysql in order to do this?

EDITED //

It's definetley the between function going wrong. I'm really unsure of what the hell is going wrong with it.

1. Can you return records between 2 dates?
2. Can you give an example?

EDITED //
Problem has been solved. It was nothing to do with the query so its safe to say this is the correct way of doing it. I had done my date ranges in a bonkers way. Thanks for all ur freaking help guys!!!!

Comment: What result does your code generate? And what result do you expect? And what's format for `e.created` field in your MySQL base?

Comment: Why do you need `CAST` anyway? You can let PHP do the conversion for you; typically `CAST` should be used on fields already in the database :)

Comment: Was following below post.. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) it states you should use [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) when using between with date or time values, so you query should be written as follows.

```
WHERE e.created BETWEEN CAST("' . $date_from . '" AS DATETIME) AND CAST("' . $date_to . '" AS DATETIME) ...
```

This may fix your problem if you are not getting the results you expect with between.

Comment: Yeah, testing myself, it doesn't seem to make a difference, don't know why the documentation states that CAST is recommended.

Comment: I've tried WHERE e.created >= "' . $date_from . '" AND e.created <="' . $date_to . '" AND  to no avail to

Comment: In cases like this I usually just run the query without the where statement, then add the different parts one by one to ensure that it's filtering as I expected.  So just specify the date parts and nothing else in the where statement, and then add on the other parts. You'll probably find that one of the parts of the where statement is incorrect for what you are actually trying to filter for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a performance difference... without CAST, it's a string comparison, but with CAST, it's a numeric comparison.  You get the same results, though, at least with that date format.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and I think you may want to apply this solution:

```
$from = $_GET['from'];
$to = $_GET['to'];
include("connect.php");
$link=Connection();
$query = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE date_time BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'";
$result=mysql_query($query,$link);
$list = array();
if($result === FALSE) {
    echo "No data";
}
```

The trick here is the signle quote, you need to put your variable inside that quote to let mysql handle it